# Prevent return from breaking the Loop

Tags: python, function, while-loop, return

I am trying to run below loop indefinately, but it seems like `return` keep breaking the loop.

I have tried with `yield`, but that produces a generator which does not work.

Any ideas as to how I can all the output of the function outside the function without break the loop?

```
import time
import cv2
import mss
import numpy
import pytesseract
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt          
from PIL import Image
import os
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

def ocr_function():
    with mss.mss() as mss_instance:
        mon = mss_instance.monitors[0]
        screenshot = mss_instance.grab(mon)                 #Read all monitor(s) 
        
    with mss.mss() as sct:
        while True:
            im = numpy.asarray(sct.grab(mon))
            plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
            text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im)      #image to text                    
            time.sleep(5)                               #One screenshot per 5 seconds 
            os.system('cls')                            #Clear output
            print(text)                                 #Print the output text  
            return text                                 #Return text to function

text = ocr_function()
text_words = set(text.split())
```

Comment: The definition of "return" is that it returns from the function (and thus must break the loop).  What exactly is it that you want to have happen to `text` at that point?  If all you want is to print the text, then just delete the `return` line.

Comment: `yield` should work. I don't know why you think it doesn't.

Comment: **Do** use a generator (*yield*). Then after calling the function: `for value in text: do_smth(value)`;

Comment: What do you want the variable `text` to be after calling `ocr_function()`? Do you want text to "accumulate" what is printed in the function somehow?  Are you potentially looking to do some kind of multiprocessing?

Comment: @FrankYellin After text is returned to the function the text will be further processed (However left that part out to focus on the core issue.

Comment: @mkrieger1 when using `yield` I get the following error since I am using `set(text.split())` later in the code.  (However left that part out to focus on the core issue)

AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @JonSG Ideally, it should no accumulate, but rather refresh every 5 second so they should work in sequence, but the `return-break` is breaking the loop, so it only updates once

Comment: @CristiFati when using `yield` I get the following error since I am using `set(text.split())`
 later in the code. `AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'split`

Comment: Carefully read my previous comment again (especially the last part).

Comment: Why do you want to use `split()`? Just don't.

Comment: @CristiFati I lack the mental capacity to understand how to proceed. Can you elaborate?

Comment: `texts_gen = ocr_function()`  `for text in texts_gen: print(text.split())` (considering that in *ocr\_function* you have `yield text`).

Comment: @CristiFati Brilliant, that works like a charm. 

Now they issues is that is does not continue with the rest of data processing. Can I store the output of `for text in texts_gen: set(text.split())` as a new variable?

Answer (score -1):

The return statement exits a function or method. Instead of using a return in your loop, you can assign the value of text in a variable.